# Issue with incorrect text in Hebrew PayPal button

Tags: html, paypal

I have a PayPal button problem
When I press the button it leads me to the payment page
But the product name
No Hebrew
You can see the picture

[image]

I also added the code of the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>bookstore</title>
</head>

<body>
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ספר בישול">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="K8003">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.99">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="17.000">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for anyone who can help

Comment: Image Link http://oi46.tinypic.com/amtwl1.jpg

Comment: see full code here http://snipt.org/zfxh0

Answer (score 9):

you can change this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="he_IL">
```

to solved your problem you can add this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
```

but there is a problem with post back hebrew text from IPN.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like this is more of a PayPal issue than an HTML/HTML5 issue.

I had a quick Google and found [this fix](http://www.webasyst.net/support/help/paypal-product-names-encoding.html):

> 1. Login to your PayPal account at http://www.paypal.com/ and proceed to the "My Account Overview -> Profile -> My Selling Tools" section.
> 2. Within "More Selling Tools" click the "PayPal Button Language Encoding" link.
> 3. Ensure that setting for "Your website’s language" is correct.
> 4. Click the "More Options" button, select the "UTF-8" option for "Encoding" and leave the "Yes" option selected for "Do you want to use
>      the same encoding for data sent from PayPal to you (e.g., IPN,
>      downloadable logs, emails)?".
> 5. Click "Save" to save your changes.